# Reference to type 'Component' claims it is defined in 'System'

Tags: c#, uwp, wmi-query, system.management

Trying to get some WMI objects in a UWP application. Running VS2015 on .net 4.6.

I'm getting errors for the ForEach and method calls stating "Reference to type 'Component' claims it is defined in 'System'" with error CS7069.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Management;

namespace SystemInfo
{
    class wmiObject
    {
        static osDetails Program()
        {

            ManagementObjectCollection osDetailsCollection = getWMIObject("SELECT OSType, caption FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");
            osDetails Details = new osDetails();

            foreach (ManagementObject mo in osDetailsCollection)
            {
                Details.OSName = mo["Caption"].ToString();

            }

            osDetailsCollection = getWMIObject("SELECT Description, NumberOfLogicalProcessors, L3CacheSize from Win32_Processor");

            foreach (ManagementObject mo in osDetailsCollection)
            {
                Details.NumberOfLogicalProcessors = mo["NumberOfLogicalProcessors"].ToString();
                Details.L3CacheSize = mo["L3CacheSize"].ToString();
                Details.Description = mo["Description"].ToString();

            }
            ;

            return Details;
        }

        static ManagementObjectCollection getWMIObject(string query)
        {
            ManagementObjectSearcher objOSDetails = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
            ManagementObjectCollection osDetailsCollection = objOSDetails.Get();
            return osDetailsCollection;

        }

        class osDetails
        {
            public string Description;
            public string OSName;
            public string NumberOfLogicalProcessors;
            public string L3CacheSize;
        }

    }


}
```

Errors

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   CS7069  Reference to type 'Component' claims it is defined in 'System', but it could not be found   SystemInfo  C:\Users\Luke\Documents\GitHub\lgDns\lgDns\SystemInfo\SystemInfo\osDetails.cs   41
Error   CS7069  Reference to type 'Component' claims it is defined in 'System', but it could not be found   SystemInfo  C:\Users\Luke\Documents\GitHub\lgDns\lgDns\SystemInfo\SystemInfo\osDetails.cs   18
Error   CS7069  Reference to type 'Component' claims it is defined in 'System', but it could not be found   SystemInfo  C:\Users\Luke\Documents\GitHub\lgDns\lgDns\SystemInfo\SystemInfo\osDetails.cs   20
Error   CS7069  Reference to type 'Component' claims it is defined in 'System', but it could not be found   SystemInfo  C:\Users\Luke\Documents\GitHub\lgDns\lgDns\SystemInfo\SystemInfo\osDetails.cs   26
Error   CS7069  Reference to type 'Component' claims it is defined in 'System', but it could not be found   SystemInfo  C:\Users\Luke\Documents\GitHub\lgDns\lgDns\SystemInfo\SystemInfo\osDetails.cs   28
Error   CS7069  Reference to type 'Component' claims it is defined in 'System', but it could not be found   SystemInfo  C:\Users\Luke\Documents\GitHub\lgDns\lgDns\SystemInfo\SystemInfo\osDetails.cs   29
Error   CS7069  Reference to type 'Component' claims it is defined in 'System', but it could not be found   SystemInfo  C:\Users\Luke\Documents\GitHub\lgDns\lgDns\SystemInfo\SystemInfo\osDetails.cs   30
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've tested the same code in a C# Console Application and it appears to work fine - with no issues with references. I've added the System.Management reference to my Universal app... Could it be a problem with the new Universal App build?

Comment: You cannot use System.Management namespace in UWP app. Check available .net API for UWP here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185501.aspx

Comment: Have you fixed it? I'm facing the same issue

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered this problem, and the solution I found was to remake the project as a C# WindowsFormsApp. It automatically added the references:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\Microsoft.CSharp.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Core.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Data.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Deployment.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Drawing.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Net.Http.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Windows.Forms.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Xml.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Xml.Linq.dll
```

Hopefully that helps someone out.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you

```
foreach (ManagementObject mo in osDetailsCollection)
{
    foreach (PropertyData prop in mo.Properties)
    {
        if(prop.Name == "Caption")
        Details.OSName = prop.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately not, its cut down on the number of errors I'm getting but still getting the same --- for each of the outer foreach and the .Get() method on osObjDetails. Thanks for looking :)