# C# MySQL - can't open connection, class not found

Tags: c#, mysql, database, connection

Trying to do

```
MySQLConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString.ToString());

try {
    // this is where it screws up
    connection.Open();
}
catch (Exception ex) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

...results in  an error: "*Reference to type 'Component' claims it is defined in 'System', but it could not be found.*"

I already have have references to **MySQL.Data** and **System.Data**.

What can I do to fix this?

Thanks in advance :))

Comment: can you get this far: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38277659

Comment: not sure what you mean by this?

Comment: Are you capable to cut and paste, add a Reference to your project for the .net, change a connection string, and run it?

Comment: Yeah, I did all that. I just pasted in the code where I'm getting the error.

Comment: And what is a screen shot of your References screen (like mine)

Comment: I think this is what you're asking for, right? https://s18.postimg.org/x15x5tpt5/Capture.png

Comment: can you show the whole error msg like in this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/32959650

Comment: Here: https://s17.postimg.org/qa9ot3srj/Capture.png, same error as in the question you linked to

Comment: works great, http://i.imgur.com/KEenNDH.jpg , (windows so note the `\r\n`) .. but you said it had tab delimiters. My input did.